# Implementing Projection onto Isotypic Component of tensor power

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, gap

Let $ G $ be a finite group. Let $ D $ be a complex representation of $ G $. Let $ \rho $ be a complex irrep of $ G $. Then the orthogonal projector of the representation $ D $ onto the $ \rho $ isotypic component is given by
$$
P_\rho=\frac{dim(\rho)}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} \overline{\chi_\rho(g)}D(g)
$$
Here the complex conjugate $ \overline{\chi_\rho(g)} $ can equivalently be written as $\chi_\rho(g^{-1}) $. And the dimension of the irrep $ dim(\rho) $ can equivalently be written as the character evaluated at the identity $ \chi_{\rho}(e) $. This formula for the projector onto the $ \rho $ isotypic component can be found for example here

[Deriving the projection onto the isotypic component](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942105/deriving-the-projection-onto-the-isotypic-component)

here

[Conceptual description of the isotypical component](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180685/conceptual-description-of-the-isotypical-component)

and here

[Central idempotent of a group representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501227/central-idempotent-of-a-group-representation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I am interested in the case where $ G $ is a finite matrix group and $ D $ is the $ n $th tensor power of the natural representation of $ G $. In that case the isotypic projector  for an irrep $ \rho $ is given by
$$
P_\rho=\frac{dim(\rho)}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} \overline{\chi_\rho(g)}\;g^{\otimes n}
$$

**Question**: How do I calculate this projection matrix in GAP?

**Pseudocode**: (just an attempt)

(chi(I)/Size(G))* Sum(G,x->ComplexConjugate(chi(x))*TensorPower(x,n));

where chi  is the character of $ \rho $. Perhaps a better attempt breaks up the sum as

(chi(I)/Size(G))* Sum(ConjugacyClasses(G),x->ComplexConjugate(chi(x))*(Sum(ElementsOf(x),y->TensorPower(y,n)));

**Bottom Line**: I'm taking tensor powers of the natural representation of a finite matrix group. I want to look at the, 7th say, tensor power and find a basis for all irreducible subreps of a particular isomorphism type $ \rho $. I believe the best way to do this (with GAP or otherwise) is to use this projector formula. If there is a better way to find a basis for these subreps (maybe one that doesn't even use GAP!) feel free to suggest it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically there, the only two changes I would do is to isolate the representation in an object (so the same code will work for other representations), and to respect that a character is given as an indexed list with positions corresponding to conjugacy classes.

Concretely (I'm picking $A_5$ in the permutation representation as random example of a matrix group):

```
gap> G:=AlternatingGroup(5);;
gap> C:=CharacterTable(G);;
gap> irrs:=Irr(C);;
```

We thus have the characters in correspondence to the conjugacy classes.

Since `TensorPower` is not a default library function, here is a way of building it:

```
TensorPower:=function(mat,n)
  return Iterated(ListWithIdenticalEntries(n,mat),KroneckerProduct);
end;
```

Next construct the representation as a homomorphism. I'm taking the 3rd tensor power of the permutation representation:

```
gap> repfct:=x->TensorPower(PermutationMat(x,5,Rationals),3);
function( x ) ... end
gap> imgs:=List(GeneratorsOfGroup(G),repfct);;
gap> rep:=GroupHomomorphismByFunction(G,Group(imgs),repfct);
MappingByFunction( Alt( [ 1 .. 5 ] ), <matrix group with
2 generators>, function( x ) ... end )
```

Now finally we can form the summation. We do this as a double sum, first summing over the indices of the conjugacy classes, and then over the elements of each class, starting with the trivial character:

```
gap> cl:=ConjugacyClasses(G);;
gap> chi:=irrs[1];;  # could take any other
gap> Length(cl);
5
proj:=Length(Image(rep,One(G)))/Size(G)*Sum([1..Length(cl)],
  i->GaloisCyc(chi[i],-1)*Sum(Elements(cl[i]),
      x->ImagesRepresentative(rep,x)));;
```

This returns a huge matrix. We can test for example its rank:

```
gap> RankMat(proj);
5
```

showing that the component for the trivial representation has dimension 5.
Similarly we find dimensions 18 (twice), 44, and 40 for the remaining irreducibles.

Comment: I'm interested in doing something like this for the Schur-Weyl type action of $ S_n $ on $ V^{\otimes n} $ where $ V=\mathbb{C}^k $. For example $ S_5 $ action on $ V^{\otimes 5} $ where $ V=\mathbb{C}^2 $. Is there an easy way to implement this in GAP? Maybe an easy way to construct this as a permutation of $ \{1,2\}^{5} $ and then use PermutationMat(). Or is there some sort of built in way for GAP to handle this kind of  Schur-Weyl type stuff? Or I can ask a new question about implementing Schur-Weyl type stuff in GAP if you feel its more appropriate to address this as a separate question.

Comment: Yes, you can use it for other situations, you just need to construct the appropriate representation as a homomorphism (the `rep`) in my example. There isn't a function `SchurWeylTypeAction`, so you would have to build it from scratch, and that probably should be another question.