# Implementing Schur-Weyl duality

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, gap

Fix some $ k $. Let $ V=\mathbb{C}^k $. Let $ G $ be any of $ GL_k,SL_k,U_k,SU_k $. I'm interested in Schur-Weyl type actions on $ V^{\otimes n} $. For the diagonal $ G $ action, the action of $ g \in G $ corresponds to just taking the $ n $th tensor power $ g^{\otimes n} $. This can be implemented in GAP as

TensorPower:=function(mat,n)
return Iterated(ListWithIdenticalEntries(n,mat),KroneckerProduct);
end;

as described here

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4498631/758507

Now I'm interested in implementing the action of the symmetric group $ S_n $ on $ V^{\otimes n} $ by permutation of the tensor factors. Currently my best guess is to consider the standard permutation action of $ S_n $ on $ \{ 1, \dots n \} $. Then consider the set of $ k^n $ functions
$$
f: \{1,\dots, n\} \to \{ 1, \dots, k \}
$$
then turn a permutation in $ S_n $ into a permutation of $ k^n $ by taking the function $ i \mapsto f(i) $ to the function $ i \mapsto f(\sigma(i)) $.

Once I have these permutations of $ k^n $ I should be able to create the matrices corresponding to the $ S_n $ action on $ V^{\otimes n} $ by just using the command

PermutationMat(x,k^n,Rationals)

**Question**: I'm looking to implement SchurWeylTypeAction of $ S_n $ on $ (\mathbb{C}^k)^{\otimes n} $ in GAP. My proposed method my work with a few pointers from someone who knows more about permutations in GAP. Or maybe some completely different method is better, I'm open to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write down matrices, corresponding to generators of $S_n$. For each generating permutation, you then get a matrix through the images of basis vectors (of the tensor product) under the group element.
Basically it will be given by the permutation of indices.

Comment: I see. So for $ S_3 $ on $ (\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes 3} \cong \mathbb{C}^8 $ the generators of $ S_3 $ are $ (12),(123) $ but as permutations of of $ \mathbb{C}^8 $ we have something like $ (12) $ becomes $ (23)(67) $ and $ (123) $ becomes $ (253)(467) $.

Comment: Yes— though you would have to tell us how you arrange the basis vectors of the tensor product for a full confirmation

Comment: ok so relabeling everything so that basis vectors are numbered by $ i=0 \dots 7 $ and the $ i $th vector corresponds to its binary expansion. For example the $ i=0 $th vector is $ |000> $ and the $ i=5 $th vector is $ |101> $. These correspond to actual vectors in $ \mathbb{C}^8 $ by $ |0>:=[1,0] $ and $ |1>:=[0,1] $ and then $ |000>:=|0> \otimes |0> \otimes |0> $ similarly  $ |101>:=|1> \otimes |0> \otimes |1> $. Now we are permuting $ 0,\dots , 7 $ instead of $ 1 , \dots , 8 $ so $ (12)  $ generator becomes $ (12)(56) $ and $ (123) $ generator becomes $ (142)(356) $. Does that seem right?

Comment: Yes, that seems right

Comment: Is there a nice way to automate this? For example if I have $ V=\mathbb{C}^2 $ and I'm interested in the action of $ S_7 $ on  $ V^{\otimes 7} $. This is already fairly difficult by hand (the orbits of $ S_7 $ on the 128 basis elements are size $ 1,7,21,35,35,21,7,1 $. For example the size 35 orbits are difficult to keep track of by hand. Is there a way to get GAP to store the 128 element set of functions $ f: \{1, \dots,7 \} \to \{ 0,1 \} $ and then turn permutations in $ S_7 $ into permutations of $ 2^7 $ by taking the function $ i \mapsto f(i) $ to the function $ i \mapsto f(\sigma(i)) $?