# Proof that distinct irreps have disjoint projectors

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, gap

Let $ \chi $ be the character of an irrep of a finite group $ G $. Let $ \pi $ be a representation of $ G $. Then the projection onto the $ \chi $ isotypic subrepresentation is given by
$$
\Pi_\chi= \frac{degree(\chi)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \overline{\chi(g)} \pi(g) 
$$
Let $ \chi_1 \neq  \chi_2 $ be characters of distinct irreps of $ G $. How do you show that
$$
\Pi_{\chi_1} \Pi_{\chi_2}=0
$$

I know the above equation must be be true but lately I've been looking at these irrep characters of $ SL(2,3) $
$$
\chi_1=(2 ,-2, 0, -\omega, -\omega^2, \omega^2, \omega)
\\
\chi_2=(2 ,-2, 0, -\omega^2, -\omega, \omega, \omega^2)
$$
For more details on these characters see

https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_special_linear_group:SL(2,3)

And I have not been getting
$$
\Pi_{\chi_1} \Pi_{\chi_2}=0
$$
What is going wrong?

Comment: I assume you're just doing the arithmetic wrong. You said what $\chi$s you picked, but what about what $\pi$? (Even if you do it in the group algebra, you should get $0$, so you could leave the $\pi(g)$s unevaluated if desired.)

Comment: @runway44 The $ \pi $ I'm using is the fifth tensor power of the irrep with character $ (2, -2, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1) $ so $ \pi $ has character  $ \chi_\pi=(32, -32, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1)  $

Comment: Its not completely clear to me how your $\Pi$ is defined. Is it an operator that applies to a representation and returns a new representation? Or is $\Pi_\chi$ supposed to be the new representation?

Comment: @ahulpke As OP has defined it, $\Pi_\chi$ is a linear combination of linear operators, so is itself a linear operator acting on the same vector space the $\pi(g)$'s are acting on.

Comment: OP, when you multiply two $\Pi$s, you can use $\pi(g)\pi(h)=\pi(gh)$ and combine like terms, so really you're just checking the appropriately general version of Schur Orthogonality holds (the actual choice of $\pi$ will be irrelevant, so long as $\chi_1,\chi_2$ correspond to inequivalent irreps - IOW, this might as well be done in the group algebra, so then applies with any $\pi$).

Comment: @ahulpke $\Pi_\chi$ is the same as $P_\rho$ in my question that you answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4496003/758507 (sorry for the inconsistency in notation between the two posts) So here $\Pi_\chi$ is a $32 \times 32$ self adjoint matrix which squares to itself (a projector). If I did it right then based on branching rules I should have $rank(\Pi_{\chi_1})=10,rank(\Pi_{\chi_2})=10,\Pi_{\chi_1}\Pi_{\chi_2}=0$ but somehow I seem to be accidentally computing the projector onto the direct sum because I'm getting $\Pi_{\chi_1}=\Pi_{\chi_2}$ and $rank(\Pi_{\chi_i})=20$ for $i=1,2$.

Comment: When I just tried what you describe, I get two $\Pi_{\chi_i}$ which both have rank 10, are different and have product 0. I strongly suspect that something went wrong in your calculation.

Comment: ya it turned out to be just a typo